# How to cancel with and without interruption using Coroutines on Android, including auto-cancellation according to lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle, kotlin-coroutines, activity-lifecycle

### Background

I'm having problems in migrating from the simple (deprecated) `AsyncTask` and `Executors` to `Kotlin Coroutines` on Android

### The problem

I can't find how I can perform the basic things I could have done on `AsyncTask` and even on `Executors` using `Kotlin Coroutines`.

In the past, I could choose to cancel a task with and without thread interruption. Now for some reason, given a task that I create on Coroutines, it's only without interruption, which means that if I run some code that has even "sleep" in it (not always by me), it won't be interrupted.

I also remember I was told somewhere that Coroutines is very nice on Android, as it automatically cancel all tasks if you are in the Activity. I couldn't find an explanation of how to do it though.

### What I've tried and found

For the Coroutines task (called `Deferred` according to what I see) I think I've read that when I create it, I have to choose which cancellation it will support, and that for some reason I can't have them both. Not sure if this is true, but I still wanted to find out, as I want to have both for best migration. Using AsyncTask, I used to add them to a set (and remove when cancelled) so that upon Activity being finished, I could go over all and cancel them all. I even made a nice class to do it for me.

This is what I've created to test this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    val bgDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        loadData()
    }

    private fun loadData(): Job = uiScope.launch {
        Log.d("AppLog", "loadData")
        val task = async(bgDispatcher) {
            Log.d("AppLog", "bg start")
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000L) //this could be any executing of code, including things not editable
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("AppLog", "$e")
            }
            Log.d("AppLog", "bg done this.isActive?${this.isActive}")
            return@async 123
        }
        //simulation of cancellation for any reason, sadly without the ability to cancel with interruption
        Handler(mainLooper).postDelayed({
            task.cancel()
        }, 2000L)
        val result: Int = task.await()
        Log.d("AppLog", "got result:$result") // this is called even if you change orientation, which I might not want when done in Activity
    }
}
```

build gradle file:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1"
```

### The questions

1. Is it possible on Coroutines to have a task that I can cancel with and without thread interruption?
2. What should be added to make this work, so that when the Activity dies (orientation change, for example), it would be auto-cancelled (with the choice of with or without interruption) ? I guess I could use a similar solution as I had for AsyncTask, but I remember I was told there is a nice way to do it for Coroutines too.

Comment: "I couldn't find an explanation of how to do it though" -- rather than creating your own scope, use an existing one tied to a lifecycle. The Jetpack provides them for activity lifecycles, fragment lifecycles, and viewmodel lifecycles. Note that doing long-running stuff in an activity has been bad form for years; coroutines does not really change that.

Comment: @CommonsWare It was for POC, and to learn how to make it work even without Activity. The Activity part was an extra thing I want to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, coroutines do not do thread interrupts - as per the [Making computation code cancellable documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#making-computation-code-cancellable), using [`yield()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html) or checking `isActive` allows coroutine aware code to participate in cancellation.

However, when interfacing with blocking code where you *do* want a thread interrupt, this is precisely the use case for [runInterruptible()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-interruptible.html), which will cause the contained code to be thread interrupted when the coroutine scope is cancelled.

This works perfectly with [lifecycle-aware coroutine scopes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecycle-aware), which automatically cancel when the `Lifecycle` is destroyed:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val bgDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        loadData()
    }

    private fun loadData(): Job = lifecycleScope.launch {
        Log.d("AppLog", "loadData")
        val result = runInterruptible(bgDispatcher) {
            Log.d("AppLog", "bg start")
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000L) //this could be any executing of code, including things not editable
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("AppLog", "$e")
            }
            Log.d("AppLog", "bg done this.isActive?${this.isActive}")
            return@runInterruptible 123
        }
        Log.d("AppLog", "got result:$result")
    }
}
```

Comment: While I don't get why it's not interruptiple by default (it's a very basic thing in threads, and should support other kinds of code that might not be based on Kotlin at all, including network handling or even just joining of threads), now with what you created, how can I cancel it with interrupting, and how can I cancel it without interrupting? Also, do I cancel the "Job" returned by the "loadData", or as I wrote originally, this time by your "runInterruptible" ?

Comment: Seems what you get from `runInterruptible` can't be cancelled. It's the result itself. Also it's worth mentioning that this requires a dependency of `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"` . I still don't get now how, from what you've created, I can choose how to cancel it. Where is the equivalent of AsyncTask to choose if I want to cancel it with interruption, and without?

Comment: "how can I cancel it with interrupting" - that's what `runInterruptible` does. "how can I cancel it without interrupting" - don't use `runInterruptible` within your `launch` and it won't be thread interrupted. "how do I cancel the "Job" returned by the "loadData"" - call `cancel()` on the resulting `Job` or rely on the automatic cancellation when the scope is cancelled (i.e., when the `Lifecycle` is destroyed).

Comment: I mean how can I choose whether I want to cancel with interruption, and choose without interruption? Here, I will show you using AsyncTask: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#cancel(boolean) . It has a parameter to tell if you want to cancel the task, or you want to cancel including interruption of the thread. What's the equivalent here? Also why aren't Coroutines cancellable by default using both kinds, if they are supposed to replace AsyncTask?

Comment: Your job writing a suspending function is to make it safe to cancel. The calling code does not get to choose how that cancellation happens. That means the choice to use `runInterruptible` is an implementation detail of your method interfacing with blocking code you don't control and is purposefully not part of the public API surface.

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't I choose how to cancel it after I created it? There is a difference between marking as cancelled which should be checked if it's cancelled or not, and doing it with interruption. Isn't there any way to overcome this weird limitation?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'marking for cancellation'. A coroutine is either cancelled or not.

Comment: I know. I meant that this is how it works, because it has a function to check if it's cancelled ("isActive") . Please read the link I've provided. As Coroutines are supposed to replace the deprecated AsyncTask, it should be able to do both for a given task.

Comment: *You* control your code. *You* have the tools to support the correct type of cancellation for the code you write and *you* have the tools to wrap code you do not control appropriately.

Comment: That's incorrect. I can't always control my code. If I run a function that's outside of the project which I only know that can run in the background, it might support just interruption, while I would want to be able to stop it, and also be able to cancel without interruption.

Comment: The responsibility to handle cancellation correctly lies on the person implementing a `suspend` method. That is purposefully not something anything outside of the method gets to control.

Comment: What if the suspend method includes calls to functions that are not under any responsibility ?

Comment: `runInterruptible` is available to wrap any blocking code that is not aware of cancellation as per it's documentation, which I linked to.

Comment: But then I lose the option to cancel it without interruption.

Comment: Seeing that you show it's impossible, I requested to have it, here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2509 . I mark this as answer only because it says that currently it's impossible, and that I have to choose in the beginning which type of cancellation I want to support, and it also shows how to be "attached" to the lifecycle.

Answer (score 7):

Coroutines aren't magic. They're implemented using state machines, and may have a number of suspension points. This is all explained in the original [Coroutines KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md).

Cancellation happens on those suspension points. A coroutine cannot be cancelled at any other point than a suspension point (in normal execution at least). If you use `Thread.sleep`, then there's no suspension points. You should use `delay` instead of `sleep`, which introduces a suspension point. If you're doing a long operation, you can add a few `yield()` to add suspension points and make your coroutine cancellable.

From [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancelling-coroutine-execution):

> Coroutine cancellation is cooperative. A coroutine code has to cooperate to be cancellable. All the suspending functions in kotlinx.coroutines are cancellable. They check for cancellation of coroutine and throw CancellationException when cancelled. However, if a coroutine is working in a computation and does not check for cancellation, then it cannot be cancelled

Calling a `suspend` function automatically introduces a suspension point.

As @CommonsWare pointed out, there's is rarely a reason to create your coroutine scope. In activities and fragments, or any component tied with a lifecycle, you should use `lifecycleScope`. In ViewModels, there's `viewModelScope`.

**EDIT:**

I've tried adapting the source of `runInterruptible` to *not* interrupt under a certain condition: passing an instance of a custom exception class `InterruptionException` as a cancel cause will skip the thread interruption. I've replaced atomicfu constructs with `AtomicInteger`, I assumed your target was only the JVM. You'll need to opt-in internal coroutines API by adding the `-Xopt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.InternalCoroutinesApi` compiler flag.

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> runInterruptibleCancellable(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    block: () -> T
): T = withContext(context) {
    try {
        val threadState = ThreadState(coroutineContext.job)
        threadState.setup()
        try {
            block()
        } finally {
            threadState.clearInterrupt()
        }
    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        throw CancellationException("Blocking call was interrupted due to parent cancellation").initCause(e)
    }
}

private const val WORKING = 0
private const val FINISHED = 1
private const val INTERRUPTING = 2
private const val INTERRUPTED = 3

private class ThreadState(private val job: Job) : CompletionHandler {
    /*
       === States ===

       WORKING: running normally
       FINISH: complete normally
       INTERRUPTING: canceled, going to interrupt this thread
       INTERRUPTED: this thread is interrupted

       === Possible Transitions ===

       +----------------+         register job       +-------------------------+
       |    WORKING     |   cancellation listener    |         WORKING         |
       | (thread, null) | -------------------------> | (thread, cancel handle) |
       +----------------+                            +-------------------------+
               |                                                |   |
               | cancel                                  cancel |   | complete
               |                                                |   |
               V                                                |   |
       +---------------+                                        |   |
       | INTERRUPTING  | <--------------------------------------+   |
       +---------------+                                            |
               |                                                    |
               | interrupt                                          |
               |                                                    |
               V                                                    V
       +---------------+                              +-------------------------+
       |  INTERRUPTED  |                              |         FINISHED        |
       +---------------+                              +-------------------------+
    */
    private val _state = AtomicInteger(WORKING)
    private val targetThread = Thread.currentThread()

    // Registered cancellation handler
    private var cancelHandle: DisposableHandle? = null

    fun setup() {
        cancelHandle = job.invokeOnCompletion(onCancelling = true, invokeImmediately = true, handler = this)
        // Either we successfully stored it or it was immediately cancelled
        while (true) {
            when (val state = _state.get()) {
                // Happy-path, move forward
                WORKING -> if (_state.compareAndSet(state, WORKING)) return
                // Immediately cancelled, just continue
                INTERRUPTING, INTERRUPTED -> return
                else -> invalidState(state)
            }
        }
    }

    fun clearInterrupt() {
        /*
         * Do not allow to untriggered interrupt to leak
         */
        while (true) {
            when (val state = _state.get()) {
                WORKING -> if (_state.compareAndSet(state, FINISHED)) {
                    cancelHandle?.dispose()
                    return
                }
                INTERRUPTING -> {
                    /*
                     * Spin, cancellation mechanism is interrupting our thread right now
                     * and we have to wait it and then clear interrupt status
                     */
                }
                INTERRUPTED -> {
                    // Clear it and bail out
                    Thread.interrupted()
                    return
                }
                else -> invalidState(state)
            }
        }
    }

    // Cancellation handler
    override fun invoke(cause: Throwable?) {
        if (cause is InterruptionException) {
            while (true) {
                when (val state = _state.get()) {
                    // Working -> try to transite state and interrupt the thread
                    WORKING -> {
                        if (_state.compareAndSet(state, INTERRUPTING)) {
                            targetThread.interrupt()
                            _state.set(INTERRUPTED)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                    // Finished -- runInterruptible is already complete, INTERRUPTING - ignore
                    FINISHED, INTERRUPTING, INTERRUPTED -> return
                    else -> invalidState(state)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun invalidState(state: Int): Nothing = error("Illegal state $state")
}

class InterruptionException(cause: Throwable?) : CancellationException() {
    init {
        initCause(cause)
    }
}

fun Job.interrupt(cause: Throwable? = null) {
    this.cancel(InterruptionException(cause))
}

suspend fun Job.interruptAndJoin() {
    interrupt()
    return join()
}
```

You can use the `interrupt` and `interruptAndJoin` extension functions to trigger thread interruption, otherwise use `cancel` for non-interrupting cancel. An example:

```kotlin
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
val job = scope.launch {
    runInterruptibleCancellable {
        // some blocking code
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        if (!isActive) {
            println("cancelled")
        } else {
            println("completed")
        }
    }
}
job.invokeOnCompletion {
    if (it is InterruptionException) {
        print("interrupted")
    }
}

runBlocking {
//  job.interruptAndJoin()  // prints "interrupted"
//  job.cancelAndJoin()     // prints "cancelled"
    job.join()              // prints "completed"
}
```

This example is the only testing I've made. It *seems* to work. I don't know if it leaks, I don't know if it's thread-safe. I'm really far out of my expertise to be honest. Please don't use it in production without further confirmation that it works.

Comment: Magic or not, it's supposed to be a replacement to things we could do before, whether it's something deprecated (AsyncTask) or very basic that can't be deprecated (thread pools and everything related to threads).  It should support code that isn't even in Kotlin, so you can't say that I should use "yield", because not always it's even editable (library, for example) or in Kotlin. Code that might have sleep/join, for example, or network. As for lifecycleScope and viewModelScope, this is nice, but what about things that occur on singleton places ? Network operations? WorkManager?

Comment: Use `Dispatchers.IO` context for network requests. While some third party code have a coroutines integration (e.g. Retrofit, Room), I guess you can just execute it in `Dispatchers.IO` otherwise and let it block. `Dispatchers.IO` has 64 threads by default so it can afford to block. WorkManager seems to have [a coroutines integration](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker), but I never used WorkManager so I can't really tell.

Comment: OK but what about cancellation? Given a task, how can I cancel it with and without interruption? ianhanniballake wrote that I can use runInterruptible, but then how can I choose if I want to cancel it with interruption, and without?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I missed the entire point of the question. I doubt you can do both. I've just tried a few things but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to have an extended class like what's returned from "runInterruptible" , that will have this functionality? Why isn't the default behavior allowing being interrupted ? It's quite a basic thing for threads to be able to interrupt them...

Comment: Coroutines are aware of cancellation. I believe supporting both cancellation and interruption for `runInterruptible` would require changing the API a lot. At this point I think you should ask on the [coroutines issue tracker](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/), they have a good record of answering such questions. And if you search for ["interruption"](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues?q=is%3Aissue+interruption) you'll find multiple interesting issues discussing it. I think you might have seen it already, I've seen your username :)

Comment: I'm not there. Should I write a request there? Also, what's the equivalent of onCancel, and even extending of the task? It seems I will have to wrap it?

Comment: I was referring to [this discussion](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/57). I tried to implement what you asked, and it seems to work. But please do ask on the coroutines issue tracker for further verification.

Comment: Oh you mean here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/57#issuecomment-657410350 . But that's how it ended: That I say that I could use only one of the choices. Not having both available at the same time. About the code, thanks, but I was hoping that there is a more official way to do it. Sorry for all the trouble. Here's the new post: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2509 . Have +1 for the effort.